# why Reference Objects hold the references of a Particular Type only

Tags: java, c#, c++

when we allocate an object on heap and store its reference using the 'new' keyword in the reference objects like this

```
Class referenceObject = new Class();
```

every thing work fine

but why cannot our 'refernceObject' hold the reference to the another type like:

```
referenceObject = new AnotherClass();
```

as the references are the memory addresses pointing to the memory location .

i mean if i have an integer type i can assign any Integral value (please avoid sizes)
let us say 1 to 10 i.e

```
 int i=1;
 i=2;
 ...
 i=10;
```

this works as we can say the type we assigning is same int for this example

what confuses me is why is not the same true for references .

more examples

i think it is like :
  we can assign any value which is the element of Set(Integers) to 'i',
 but we cannot assign any value which is the element of Set(References) to 'objectReference'

if it is like this what is the reason ?

any suggestion/help is welcomed and appretiated

**To Downvoters: please comment your reason for downvoting or is it like you can't answer this**

Comment: _or is it like you can't answer this_ - a sure way to get more downvotes

Comment: In C++ many things of what you wrote don't make sense. You're probably getting downvotes because you've added totally different and unrelated tags without having studied the differences yourself first.

Comment: @MarcoA. why are tags unrelated ? you mean the expert programmer in these languages don't know this much of basics ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question?s=5|0.2324

Comment: @Reimeus i guess downvoter who cannot at least comment is just an arrogant Guy with a false intention that he knows something.

Comment: I suspect that you might get a better resolution to your potentially salvageable but poorly-asked question by working with commenters to improve it than by flinging insults at people who know what they're talking about.

Comment: @chrylis please explain "poorly-asked question" and edit the question definition to be labelled as "Greatly-Asked" and if you can't please feel free not to share any of your knowledge.

Comment: @Constantine _"please explain 'poorly-asked question'"_ It's already explained well in the links given in the [on hold] message. Calm down.

Comment: thanks to all the Link Jockeys for wasting me Time

Comment: Use `Object` it would hold everything(any type), but you have to know about the held object for casting.

Answer (score 4):

Java is a strongly typed languages. Therefore, when you declare a variable of type `SomeClass`, it can only refer to instances of `SomeClass` or sub-classes of `SomeClass`. Based on the fact that the variable has a specific type, the compiler allows you to call only methods declared for that type (or super-classes of that type).

Comment: what have Types to do with refernces ?

Comment: @Constantine"A variable is a storage location and has an associated type, sometimes called its compile-time type, that is either a primitive type (§4.2) or a reference type (§4.3). [...] Compatibility of the value of a variable with its type is guaranteed by the design of the Java programming language" ([JLS 4.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.2))

Comment: @Constantine If you treat a reference as a type-less pointer to some memory address, then you are no longer in a strongly typed language such as Java. Java has references, not pointers. References always have a type.

Comment: On the other hand, python is a strongly typed language, yet to can bind references to objects of any type.

Comment: @juanchopanza No, Python is weakly typed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 2 classes. `Bird` and `Human`.

When you declare a variable `Bird tweety;` You say that tweety is a bird and it must hold a `Bird` object.

If you assign `tweety = new Human();` you will get a compile time error because `tweety` is a `Bird` and can't hold a `Human` object.

Comment: thanks for your answer your answer is quit write in terms of readability but i want to know what are types distinguished-on internally.

Comment: I don't know about the implementation details.